# No database instance with id:' ' found. Please specify a valid db instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm going to use Amazon RDS for my Spring boot web application
So, I created RDS with 'mainrds' instance id [Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGZFb.png). then I configured `application.properties` like this:

```
#RDS
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds.username=dbadmin
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds.password=password
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds.readReplicaSupport=false
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds.databasename=maindata
```

When I run the application, I encountered these error messages:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No database instance with id:'mainrds' found. Please specify a valid db instance
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.getDbInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:170)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createDataSourceInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:151)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:129)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 178 common frames omitted
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. what is the missing point?

Comment: Can you explain how you are providing this property file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.

`spring-cloud-aws` probably can't resolve the proper `aws region` on it's own. If you're only on one region, insert this into your properties file with the region where your RDS instance is placed.

```
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
```

This solved the problem for me.

You could also try with:

```
cloud.aws.region.auto=true
```

to see if the EC2 meta data service can resolve the correct region.

It is also possible to connect via. normal spring-boot settings, where you simply specify the RDS instance endpoint in the url of the datasource like so: (for a postgresql instance)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://endpoint.of.rds.instance.amazonaws.com:5432/dbname
```

and of course supply the `datasource.platform`, `datasource.username`, `datasource.password`, `spring.database.driverClassName` and `spring.jpa.database` in your application.properties aswell.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

After some debugging I found the application.properties as given in the question is not correct:

```
#RDS
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds #this line has to be deleted
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds.username=dbadmin
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds.password=password
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds.readReplicaSupport=false
cloud.aws.rds.mainrds.databasename=maindata
```

After deleting the line `cloud.aws.rds.mainrds` everything worked just fine.

Using `spring.datasource.*` is not an option because we are using IAM authentication for RDS and therefore the password has to be regenerated every 15 minutes.